# Redefine url('/') value dynamically in Laravel custom middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Suppose, Assign `APP_URL` value at `.env` file.

```
APP_URL=www.test.com/login
```

Now from my custom middleware,

```
  echo url('/') ; //output will be base url =>(www.test.com)
```

Now question is , Is there any way to assign a new value from **my middleware** which will like

```
echo url('/') ; //output will be base url =>(www.test.com/hello)
```

And that value will be accessible from any view, controller file under that middleware .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override URL in middleware with:

```
url()->forceRootUrl('www.test.com/hello');
echo url('/');
```

Comment: is it possible to access `hello` from this url??

Comment: @MinarMnr I've updated the answer. I've tested the solution and it's working.

Comment: @Sohel0415 with `explode('/', url('/'))[$segment + 2]`

Comment: its working @AlexeyMezenin .Answer accepted .
But this solution arise another problem . Suppose, {{ asset('test.css') }} will search  file  at www.test.com/hello/test.css but actually my css file locates here .www.test.com/test.css.
Any idea how can i solve that ?

Comment: @MinarMnr I'd recommend you to not override anything. Just do `url('hello')` etc. It's a good idea to not reinvent the wheel to avoid a lot of little annoying time wasting problems like you've just described.